# Rastrear #hash e criar descrição apartir dela [LOGICA]

Tags: php, mysql, sql, twitter-api

Me deparei com isso agora e gostaria de debater para criarmos uma lógica.

Pois bem, hoje em dia é usado muito as hashtags para tudo nas principais redes sociais, eu quase nunca entro no Twitter e quando entro me deparo com hashtags estranhas e não sei do que eles estão falando, isso deixa o usuário um pouco perdido, e se existisse um mecanismo que criasse uma descrição da tal hashtag? Que descrevesse em pequenas linhas o que eles estão falando pra mostrar ao usuário e não deixalo perdido.

Me lembro de ler uma notícia em que o Twitter estava planejando/lançando algo assim porém não encontrei pra buscar mais informações, o "mecanismo" teria que seguir 3 regras de praxe:

- Ser totalmente automático, sem ajuda humana pra criar a descrição
- Ser programado em PHP e MySQL
- Máximo de 200 caracteres para a descrição.

Com meus pensamento em off eu imaginei que teríamos que pegar as mensagens que contenham a HASHTAG X no banco, ver palavras que tenham em comum, apartir disso ele pesquisa em um banco de dados e monta a descrição, eu penso assim e vocês?

Comment: Nao entendi o porque do negativo sem um motivo. Maas ENFIM.

Comment: O site é para perguntas e respostas **objetivas** sobre questões **técnicas**. Essa pergunta é ampla, discursiva e fora do escopo de programação. Não se encaixa no nosso foco: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Estou votando para fechar como "primariamente baseada em opiniões". Mas fora a questão do tópico, não há nada de errado na pergunta, não há por que negativar.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal seria uma pergunta com uma resposta util que ajudaria futuramente a muitas pessoas tendo em vista que meu foco é como fazer isso em MySQL e PHP, nao seria interessante?

Comment: Ainda assim, é sempre necessário que seja possível escolher uma resposta como "A resposta correta". Além disso a pergunta deve ser claramente objetiva e sem nenhum tipo de opinião pessoal. Perguntas opinativas não produzem respostas, produzem apenas um monte de opiniões que não são uma melhor que a outra. Se o foco é como fazer em MySQL e PHP, então a pergunta não demonstra esse foco. E ainda assim, seria muito ampla porque pergunta como fazer o sistema inteiro, não tem como responder isso. Uma resposta "correta e definitiva" seria um livro, ou faria o sistema por você. Entende?

Comment: De qualquer forma, pode abrir uma pergunta lá no [meta] que é onde discutimos sobre a comunidade em si. Lá seria o lugar para perguntar sobre essa pergunta e discutir se ela deveria ou não ser aceita. Todas as nossas regras podem ser alteradas/melhoradas por discussão lá.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supondo que a pergunta seja de fato on-topic e não baseada em opiniões (não tenho plena certeza, mas estou lhe dando o benefício da dúvida), me parece que o que você quer é implementar em PHP e MySQL um algoritmo que invente automaticamente, para cada hashtag uma descrição de no máximo 200 caracteres para ela. É isso?

Se estiver certo, o seu problema cai em uma área de inteligência artificial muito complicada, pois o sistema teria que analisar os textos relacionados a cada hashtag, **entender o que eles significam e qual é a relação deles entre si e então bolar uma descrição que faça sentido**.

Ou seja, o seu algoritmo vai ter que ser capaz de entender um texto aonde alguém comemora o gol, ou reclama de determinado político ou fala o que achou da novela, ou conta sobre a viagem para o exterior, ou conta uma piada interna de um determinado grupo... Para piorar, as pessoas frequentemente escrevem textos com uma péssima ortografia, escrevem em várias línguas diferentes e usam as hashtags de modo totalmente incoerente. Ou seja, é melhor você esquecer esta ideia.

Com o algoritmo que você está supondo, o máximo que você consegue ter é um monte de palavras que você sabe que aparecem nos textos com a hashtag. Mas, e daí? Um amontoado de palavras de significado desconhecido por si só não forma uma descrição inteligível de nada.

Comment: seria bastante complicado, mas eu segui uma logica menos artificial e consegui criar o algoritmo que faz isso, muito obrigado!